# aurelia-fetch-client.d.ts undefined symbols

Tags: javascript, aurelia

When I include aurelia-fetch-client in my project, I get some errors that I can't resolve. It says that it can't find: Request, Response, Headers, BufferSource, URLSearchParams, as you can see in the following image:

[image]

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the typescript definition file for whatwg-fetch:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/whatwg-fetch/whatwg-fetch.d.ts

Here's more info on the fetch spec:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Still error when using [whatwg-fetch.d.ts from DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9ca83b/whatwg-fetch/whatwg-fetch.d.ts). (for now) you must use [this version of whatwg-fetch.d.ts](https://github.com/aurelia/fetch-client/blob/1adb2c/doc/whatwg-fetch.d.ts). See [fetch-client/issues/15](https://github.com/aurelia/fetch-client/issues/15)

Answer (score 6):

## Install whatwg-fetch types with typings.

It's possible use [`typings`](https://github.com/typings/typings) to install the whatwg-fetch types.

```
npm install typings --global
typings install dt~whatwg-fetch --global
```

The above installs them from [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/) (`dt`).

## Install whatwg-fetch types with npm (TypeScript 2.0).

```
npm install --save @types/whatwg-fetch
```

## Further Tweaks

Note: TypeScript might still complain that it "Cannot find name 'URLSearchParams'." We can fix that by adding the an interface to one of our typings files. For instance:

**custom_typings/adhoc_interfaces.d.ts**

```
interface URLSearchParams {}
```

Comment: I also had to add  interface ReadableStream {}